# Problem with spacing of indented columns

Tags: koma-script, paracol

I use the `paracol` package to divide some text in columns. The columns should be indented. For this purpose I use the `\addmargin`-command of koma-script. This approach indents not only the first column but even the second column.

I want

- "indent - column 1 - normal (yellow) space - column 2"

instead of

- "indent - column 1 - indent - column 2"

Look at the following picture. The second indent should be the normal (yellow) indent.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

  \begin{paracol}{2}
      \Blindtext[1]
    \switchcolumn
      \Blindtext[1]
  \end{paracol}

  \begin{addmargin}[2cm]{0cm}
    \blindtext[1]\\
  \end{addmargin}

  \begin{addmargin}[2cm]{0cm}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \blindtext[1]
      \switchcolumn
        \blindtext[1]
    \end{paracol}
  \end{addmargin}

\end{document}
```

Comment: addmargin is a list environment (like itemize or enumerate) and therefore takes place INSIDE the column.   It doesn't actually change the margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can create a 3 column `paracol` using `\setcoumnwidth` with the first column acting as a spacer.  I didn't have much luck trying to adjust the gaps between columns, so I just included `\columnsep` in the calculations.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full,showframe]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paracol}

\newlength{\tempwidth}

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\tempwidth=\dimexpr \textwidth-2cm-\columnsep\relax
\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr 2cm-\columnsep\relax,0.5\tempwidth,0.5\tempwidth}
\begin{paracol}{3}
  \rlap{\rule{2cm}{1pt}}
  \switchcolumn[1]
    \blindtext
  \switchcolumn[2]
    \blindtext
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: In your solution `\tempwidth` is equal to `\dimexpr \textwidth-2cm-\columnsep\relax`, but one line below you write `\dimexpr 2cm-\columnsep\relax`. Can you explain the difference (minus before 2cm)?

Comment: The space before the second column is 2cm, but that includes the intercolumn gap (\columnsep), so the actual width of the first column is 2cm-\columnsep. OTOH, \tempwidth is the remaining space available for the 2 equal columns. (One can compute each column width directly using \dimexpr 0.5\textwidth - 1cm -0.5\columnsep\relax but that is somewhat more confusing.)